# Docker compose build exited 137 (out of memory)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've a memory constrained environment (~160mb ram free) with a service running using a simple docker-compose file:

```
version: "2"

services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - admin-app
  admin-app:
    build: .
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PORT=80
```

I need to rebuild and restart it, but when I do it using `docker-compose up -d --build`, I receive an error:

```
ERROR: Service 'admin-app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 137
```

This is the output of `docker ps -a` showing failed builds:

```
75f0695af77f "/bin/sh -c 'npm i..."   11 minutes ago   Exited (137) 8 minutes ago
44d7d9e8ec06 "/bin/sh -c 'npm i..."   15 minutes ago   Exited (137) 14 minutes ago
4e3f159dd183 "/bin/sh -c 'npm i..."   19 minutes ago   Exited (137) 17 minutes ago
```

How can I set a build memory limit in docker-compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker-compose` doesn't have any option to set memory limit for the build. Your best bet is to build individually

```
docker build -m 60m .
docker build -m 60m nginx
```

And then run your `docker-compose up -d` command